# ID/Key for values in Typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am using Typeahead in my project (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and it is working well giving me all suggestions I need from the DB.

Say, I am giving the user, a list of his friends in suggestions through typeahead as he types. Say that I am looking for a user's first and last names for giving the result. **And say that multiple users have same first and/or lastname.**

It gives the suggestions in typeahead which is fine but when the user selects the input from typeahead suggestions, **how do I identify that on the server side?** (Does typeahead allow some kind of ID to be set for every element I add).

PS: I am actually using typeahead in conjunction with http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ for the tags feature

Comment: have you been able to solve this? i am having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992303/how-to-get-id-and-value-from-twitter-bootstrap-and-bloodhound-suggestion

Comment: @user2707590: nope, i switched to select2 instead. typeahead is not meant for this purpose. you cant set id key values

Comment: `$('input#myInput').typeahead({options}, {/*data set options*/}).bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
            $('input#hiddenInput').val(suggestion.id);
        })` this works out great.

Comment: @user2707590: yes.. but this is a workaround.. with hidden input.. no direct way to do it.. but if this works for you, good.