# How to get id and value from twitter bootstrap and bloodhound suggestion?

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

How to get both id and value from typeahead.js when selecting a suggestion?

I have a json as follows:

```
[
    {id:1, name:'paul'}, 
    {id:2, name:'jim'}, 
    {id:3, name:'tom'}, 
    {id:4, name:'medor'}, 
    {id:5, name:'janzy'}
]
```

and i created Bloodhound object as follows:

```
var bh = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '//localhost/data/names.json',
    identify: function(datum){
        return datum.id;    
    }
});
```

and i instantiated typeahead as follows:

```
$('#name').typeahead({"highlight":true}, {
    "name":"name",
    "source":bh,
    "display":"value",
    "limit":10
})
```

I want to be able to get the `id` when i submit my form. When i submit the following example, i obtain only the `name` attribute.

i tried to obtain the id via javascript as follows:

```
$('#name').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion){
    console.log(suggestion);
})
```

but `suggestion` contains an object with only text value which i selected

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options.

I think overriding the `identity` function may get you what you need.  Something like this might get you there:

```
identify: function(datum){
        return { id: datum.id, value: data.name};    
    }
```

I use `remote` for my actual production code and use the `filter` option to return the display value as well as the key value.

It looks something like this:

```
remote: {
        url: '/some/url',
        filter: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                return $.map(data, function (object) {
                    return { id: object.id, value: object.name};
                });
            } else {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also try using the `transform` function as part of `prefetch`, which would look something like this:

```
prefetch: {
        url: '/some/url',
        transform: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                return $.map(response, function (object) {
                    return { id: object.id, value: object.name};
                });
            } else {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
```

The documentation ([available here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)) is somewhat helpful, but doesn't do much to show more complicated examples.

I also experimented with the examples ([typeahead examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)) quite a bit before I finally found my answers.